# How do I find someone I have started courting?

Tags: guild-2

So I'm playing for the first time and I started courting someone. Suddenly I had an appointment in the town hall to get to. Fast forward a few hours and I have no idea how to find the person I was previously courting.

Can anyone tell me how to find them?

Comment: She gave you a fake number... classic tactic for "oh he is cute but I don't see anything long term"... sorry about your luck..

Comment: She should be in your "persons of interest" book. My game refuses to work right now, so I can't verify where exactly, but it's probably courtship candidates or family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spyglass in the bottom right you can find a spyglass where "interesting persons" are located, there you can find before you start courting "good marriage candidates" as well as the person being courted at the moment.

Comment: Might aswell mention that due to death or some other events that person may stop courting you and not be on the "persons being courted by" list. Also, if you don't court for a while, you'll receive a message and from then on you can find that person by clicking on their portrait.